# Getting JSON through HttpUrlConnection is too slow

Tags: android, json, httpurlconnection

I'm getting some JSON from my server using HHtp(s)UrlConenction. However this is too slow, especially the part getting the `InputStream`.

The JSON is provided by my own server. As an example, the iOs version of this app get it in maybe one second. Here it can goes up to 5/6 seconds, which is killing the responsive aspect of the app.

Here is the process I'm using to get the json:

```
    URL url;
    // get URL content
    url = new URL(apiURL);
    conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
    conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(false);
    conn.setHostnameVerifier(AsyncConnect.DO_NOT_VERIFY);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    conn.setRequestProperty(MainActivity.API_TOKEN, MainActivity.ENCRYPTED_TOKEN);

    in=conn.getInputStream(); // slowest part so far, several seconds spent there

    // open the stream and put it into BufferedReader
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

    while ((line=br.readLine())!= null) {
        builder.append(line);
    }

    result=builder.toString();
    //System.out.print(result);
    br.close();



} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    result=null;
} catch (IOException e) {
    result=null;
} catch (Exception e) {
    result=null;
}
finally {
    try {
        in.close();
    }catch(Exception e){}
    try {
        conn.disconnect();
    }catch(Exception e){}

    return result;
}
```

Why is it that slow? I know I probably should have use Volley or Retrofit, but I was beginner as this moment and I didnt have any idea about how to use them. And I'm not even sure it would be faster, especially with hhtps.

Do you guys have a way to increase the speed of this process? This is just sending me a string and shouldnt be that long. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: maybe issue is at server side? did you try another urls with same code?

Comment: You can try Retrofit. I also in misunderstanding the UrlConnection is best but after do some R&D, Based on response statistics Retrofit is very much faster than Asynch(70-90%) & compare to Volley(40-60%) check this link :-http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/

Comment: @Ajinkya it won't help to solve 5-6 seconds delay

Comment: But this is https. Will it work with https? It needs to go through the possible handshakes / security troubles